# Is mixing modules and headers in C++20 possible / acceptable?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm actually trying to understand the C++20 modules system by writing my own little module. Let's say I want to provide a function that deletes all the spaces at the beginning and the end of a string (a `trim` function). The following code **works without problem**.

```cpp
module;

export module String;

import std.core;

export std::string delete_all_spaces(std::string const & string)
{
    std::string copy { string };

    auto first_non_space { std::find_if_not(std::begin(copy), std::end(copy), isspace) };
    copy.erase(std::begin(copy), first_non_space);

    std::reverse(std::begin(copy), std::end(copy));
    first_non_space = std::find_if_not(std::begin(copy), std::end(copy), isspace);
    copy.erase(std::begin(copy), first_non_space);
    std::reverse(std::begin(copy), std::end(copy));

    return copy;
}
```

```cpp
import std.core;
import String;

int main()
{
    std::cout << delete_all_spaces("  Hello World!    \n");
    return 0;
}
```

But **what if I want to use only specific headers instead of `std.core` in my module?** If I do so, replacing the `import std.core` by the following code, I get an error on Visual Studio 2019.

```cpp
module;

#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

export module String;

// No more import of std.core

export std::string delete_all_spaces(std::string const & string)
{
    // ...
}
```

```
Error LNK1179 file not valid or damaged: '??$_Deallocate@$07$0A@@std@@YAXPAXI@Z' COMDAT duplicated
```

However, if in the `main.cpp` I remplace as well the `import std.core` with `#include <iostream>`, the code compiles again. It's like **using both system provents the linker to do its job**.

The question is: **am I doing it wrong**? Is it a bad practice to use both the new `import` and the old `#include` methods? I saw on multiple posts on the Internet that you can include some old headers in your module, thus modernizing your code without breaking the existing. But **what if this header includes some part of the STL, like `#include <string>`** but my module uses `import std.core`?

I'm testing only with Visual Studio 2019 because, as of now, `import std.core` does not work with GCC. So, **may it comes from a bug in VS**? **Or will the problem be the same for all compilers?**

Comment: `std.core` is an implementation-defined module that exports (most of) the symbols in the standard library, gcc doesn't have it because Microsoft made it up

Comment: Oh, thanks, I thought this was standard and not Microsoft-specific. So the only standard way are the yet not supported (on VS 2019) `import <file>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, modules can be used together with header files. we can both import and include headers in the same file, this is an example:

```
import <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,6,8,7};
  for (auto i:v)
    std::cout<<i;
  return 0;
}
```

When you create modules, you're free to export entities in the interface file of the module and move the implementations to other files. to conclude, the logic is the same as in managing .h and .cpp files

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that Visual Studio 2019 is bugging on that particular point?

Comment: Yes, I think it’s a bug according to this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1252218/c20-modules-still-does-not-work-in-new-visual-stud.html . As far as I see, MSVC use std.core, std.filesytem, std.memory.. but you want to use specific headers and you’re totally right. But I think it’s an issue and it’s reported. We have to wait meanwhile I’ll ask a friend in Microsoft about the progress on this topic and I’ll give you feddbacks as soon as possible

Comment: I asked a Microsoft engineer and told me; still work in progress, so we have to wait

Comment: With VS Studio 16.9.1, the problem seems to be fixed, because the code in the question (mix with `import std.core` and C-includes), who was faulty before, now compiles. But the `import <header>` still doesn't work.

Comment: With Visual Studio 16.10.0, the problem is completely fixed and one can use the `import <header>` syntax.

Comment: That’s great. Happy coding then :)